# Event handling in ReactVR

Tags: javascript, virtual-reality, webvr, react-360

Been experimenting with ReactVR  and i have few doubts in handling events.As per the documentation in [Cusors and Input](https://facebook.github.io/react-vr/docs/input.html),finding out the type of event is as easy as reading `type` of the event.

> Events coming into onInput can be further filtered by inspecting the
>   type field, which will be one of 'MouseInputEvent',
>   'KeyboardInputEvent', 'TouchInputEvent', or 'GamepadInputEvent'

But in the below code `event.type` gives `undefined`.

```
_onInput(event) {
    console.log(event.type);//undefined
}
```

i was eventually able to sniff the event type by doing

```
_onInput(event) {
    let syntheticEvent = event.nativeEvent.inputEvent;
    console.log(syntheticEvent.type);
}
```

Is this the expected behaviour or am i missing something.

Few related questions

1. Do we have to sniff events with event.nativeEvent?
2. How do we find out the target of the event, for eg if i am to bind
   an `onInput` event to a `Plane` , currently inspecting the
   `event.nativeEvent` gives the `target` as a numerical value? Not
   helpful at all.
3. Finally, the ReactJS way of calling events doesn't seem to work in
   ReactVR. For eg, in the former we would just

   ```
   <Plane onInput={this._onInput} lit={true} />
   ```

   But this doesnt work , in the latter we have to

   ```
   <Plane onInput={(event) => this._onInput(event)} lit={true} />
   ```

   Why is this?

*Note:i have some exp with ReactJS and ZERO with React Native, i am guessing ReactVR inclines towards the latter pardon if it is obvious*

Comment: On of the main contributors explained this a bit [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-vr/issues/112). Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the event object in react is reused and gets flushed immediately after it goes out of the function scope therefore you have to store it as a variable for further use.

Comment: erm ... but it hasn't gotten out of the function scope yet , so shouldn't it be accessible inside the _onInput() ? The question is more of why we are accessing the event type in this manner  as described in the question.

Comment: It's well described in the docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html

Comment: Believe it or not console.log is asynchronous so it won’t get the result in time @alexander vitanov is correct on the way to handle it